# I have 5 fields in a form which are pre populated. Using Selenium web driver how can I verify which one of the field is empty

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, assert

I have a test case to verify a form. There are 5 fields which will be prepopulated. If any one of the field is empty, after submitting error message will come. I am fetching the text from all the fields and asserting if they are not null, asserting is failing since one field is null in these. But how to find out dynamically which field is empty.
There might be a possibility to take each field and assert each field if empty or not. but I guess that will make the code clumsy.
Any other ways by which I can do this?

Following is my code :

```
 String sender = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$textsendername1")).Text;
        String country = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ddlCountry")).Text;
        String address1 = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txtsenderaddress1")).Text;
        String city = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txtcity")).Text;
        String state = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ddlstate")).Text;
        String zip = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txtzip")).Text;

        try
        {
            Assert.IsNotEmpty(sender, country, address1, city, state, zip);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String excep = e.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(excep);
        }
```

Comment: What are you intending to do if any of them is empty? Is that a failure or just something you want to fix?

Comment: I think your are trying to get the Text property of input fields. This will give you an empty string and an Assert.Failed exception will occur in your code no matter how the fields are populated.

To retrieve the value of inputfields you need to use .GetAttribute('value') instead of .Text on the Element.

Comment: @JeffC - if any one of them is empty, then after clicking submit button, I want to verify if error message is showing or not. So I have to validate submit is not successful if anyone of them is empty.

Comment: @Frank - but can I dynamically know which element is blank? if I fetch the value and assert like : Assert.IsNotEmpty(sender, country, address1, city, state, zip); what code should I write to know which field is not satisfying IsNotEmpty?  Now, anyway this assert is failing

Comment: Why you want to use an Assert? Why not use a simple if statement, in C#: if (country.Equals("") || adress1.Equals("") etc)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function that determines if any of the fields are empty since you will likely be using this repeatedly.

```
public bool HasEmptyField()
{
    string sender = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$textsendername1")).GetAttribute("value");
    string country = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ddlCountry")).GetAttribute("value");
    string address1 = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txtsenderaddress1")).GetAttribute("value");
    string city = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txtcity")).GetAttribute("value");
    string state = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ddlstate")).GetAttribute("value");
    string zip = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txtzip")).GetAttribute("value");

    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(sender) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(address1) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(city) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(state) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(zip);
}
```

Your script would then look something like

```
bool expectError = HasEmptyField();
driver.FindElement(submitButtonLocator).Click(); // click submit button
if (expectError)
{
    Assert.True(driver.FindElements(errorMessageLocator).Any(), "Verify error message exists");
    // do something to address the error message
}
// continue the script
```

Comment: If this, or any other answer, was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.